# TypeScript "extends" generic constraint

Tags: generics, typescript, generic-constraints

I am using the `extends` constraint in TypeScript, like so:

```
class Animal {}
class Lion extends Animal {}
class Bear extends Animal {}

class ZooKeeper<T extends Animal> {
    constructor(p: T = new Animal()) {

    }
}

new ZooKeeper(new Animal());
```

But `p: T = new Animal()` contains an error:

> Type 'Animal' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>
> constructor Animal(): Animal

**Why**, and what do I do, in order that I can use `Animal`, in place of `Animal` subtypes?

[Source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Animal%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Lion%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Bear%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ZooKeeper%3CT%20extends%20Animal%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(p%3A%20T%20%3D%20new%20Animal())%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20ZooKeeper(new%20Animal())%3B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast your animal to T and it will work.

```
class ZooKeeper<T extends Animal> {
    constructor(p: T = <T>new Animal()) {

    }
}
```

According to your own comment (for future readers) you can also do:

```
class ZooKeeper<T extends Animal> {
    constructor(p: T = new Animal() as T) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that `<T>`/`as T` is not casting but type assertion. It tells transpiler “treat animal as type T event if it’s not”. E.g. the following code would fail: new ZooKeeper<Lion>().getAnimal().someLionMethod(), because animal we get is not really a Lion, but an instance of Animal class.

Comment: This works but is horribly wrong. Why do you use the generic then?

Answer (score 2):

You could just leave the assignment from the constructor parameter declaration, seems to be compiling properly for me. You can even make the parameter optional, if you may want to leave it.

**UPDATE:** As [series0ne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033686/series0ne) pointed out, this solution does not provides a default instance of `Animal` where one has not been provided!

```
class ZooKeeper<T extends Animal> {
    constructor(p?: T) {
    }
}

var zk = new ZooKeeper<Lion>(new Lion());
var zk2 = new ZooKeeper(new Animal());
var zk3 = new ZooKeeper();
```

The `ZooKeeper` class will be typed and you can access the child class specific properties of `T`.

Comment: This does not solve the problem - if you look at the emitted JS, you will see that p: T = new Animal() emits a default instance (of Animal) where one has not been provided. Your implementation will not do this!

Comment: I looked at the JS output, you are right, there is a difference. I did not understand your question fully, sorry.

Comment: No problem. All part of the learning curve, my friend. If you update your answer to incorporate my comments, I will remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it’s not easily possible to do what you’d like to do. `Animal` is not assignable to `T` because they are different types.

Consider the example:

```
class Lion extends Animal {
  roar() { … }
}
new ZooKeeper<Lion>().animal.roar();
```

You can run it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Animal%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Lion%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20roar()%20%7B%20console.log('roar')%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Bear%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ZooKeeper%3CT%20extends%20Animal%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20animal%3A%20T%20%3D%20new%20Animal()%20as%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atry%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20ZooKeeper%3CLion%3E().animal.roar()%3B%0D%0A%7D%20catch%20(E)%20%7B%20alert(E)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A) to see it throws an exception at runtime, because even we pass `Lion` as the `T` type, we explicitly create `Animal` object instead, which does not have any of `T` type members. And we cannot write `new T()` in constructor because at runtime all info about types does not exist.

It’s also worth to mention that construct `<Type>object` or `object as Type` should be used only if it’s explicitly necessary, since **it’s not casting but type assertion** (it tells compiler ‘treat `object` like it was `Type` even if it’s not’ ), so when used as “casting” it may cause hard to find errors.